# Jquery: Encoding and decoding json to/from php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, json

I have a jquery function as follows :

```
$(document).on("click",".ball_link", function fetchLevels(){
     $.getJSON('fetch_level.php',{level: clicked_ball}, function(data) {
        $.each(data, function() {
        alert(data);
        });
    });
});
```

My fetch_level.php file looks like this :

```
$clicked_ball=$_GET["level"];
$sqlget="select * from level_flow where parent_level='$clicked_ball'";
$resultget=mysql_query($sqlget);

$response_array=array();
while($rowget=mysql_fetch_assoc($resultget)){
    $response_array[]=$rowget;
}

echo json_encode($response_array);
```

The query returns 3 rows across 5 columns (all ints). I want to be able to access each of those 15 values, but alert(data) in the js code gives this :

```
([object],[Object]),([object],[Object]),([object],[Object])
```

Comment: function() {
        alert(data);
        }); data is the global XHR object. the ".each" method does not work like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Treat as Object in jQuery, eg:

```
$(document).on("click",".ball_link", function fetchLevels(){
     $.getJSON('fetch_level.php',{level: clicked_ball}, function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, name) {
            alert(name.parent_level);
        });
    });
});
```

`data` contains all your database row names with values

Answer (score 1):

Actually mysql_fetch_assoc returns an associative array, and you put that array inside another array

so in javascript you can try

```
alert(data[0].nameOfColumn);
```

You could iterate on it

```
$.each(data,function(i, el) {
    alert(el.nameOfColumn);
} );
```

in any case to see the structure of data you can use chrome or Firefox (with Firebug) and console.log(data)